# Modular ASP.NET 5 SPA with angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, single-page-application, asp.net-core

We have been working on the large project which use SPA for front end.
We have request that the application must be modular, which means that we can sell different module to different clients.
We have been trying to find best approach for the project.

We choose this approach:
One Web application with common functionality and for each module - one class library (package).
But we have problem with static files. We cannot configured Main WebApp to lookup static files in deferent location.

We try this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
  FileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(webModuleAssembly),
  RequestPath = new PathString("/Module1")
}
```

But it is not working.

We cannot find examples for that case. (We use ASP.Net 5, MVC 6-beta 8)

Do anybody have suggestion how can we solve this problem, or do you suggest another approach.

More info: Every module might have a lot of files, which include help pages, localization, images etc.

ps. We discussed about solution where we made folder for each module in the main WebApp. But sometimes we need some controllers (mvc/web api) to support client side. 
 - If we put them together in one project, we must install them to clients which did not buy it.
 - If we separate only MVC/WEB API controllers to a class library we will have problem with maintains code. **When I say MVC/WEB API controllers, I talk only about some controllers for supporting specific client side actions - we have different WebApi projects which implements business logic.**

Comment: With multiple modules, you mean multiple ASP.NET 5 applications? In that case, are the “submodules” registered in IIS using a virtual directory?

Comment: Well, we would like to use Class Library for modules instead of separate ASP.NET 5 applications - if it possible of course.

Comment: Okay, well, I was asking because there is an [open bug](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/14) that you need to set the base path for virtual directories.

Comment: Henk, were you able to find a solution to this as I was looking into a similar modularization of an application that I am working on. I have looked at the ASP.NET 5 class library and it seems to work fine for controllers (just works), views (need to be embedded resources), but the issue is with the static files. I started exploring whether the "content" folder of a NuGet package would work for the static files but I did not get it working yet.

Comment: Here is a on-going pull request to add functionality to be able to combine multiple file providers: https://github.com/aspnet/FileSystem/pull/142. I am experimenting with it now, and I am able to combine physical file provider with multiple embedded file providers. Now I only need to figure out the static file. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The real deal here will be to keep track of new plugins after your app is up and running.

Best idea is to have a base folder for all plugins (eg: wwwroot/Modules). Plugins should be there to work (to be loaded).

After that, I'd suggest creating a custom implementation of `StaticFileMiddleware`, based on the original implementation [available on GitHub here](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles/StaticFileMiddleware.cs), that:

1. Parses every request based on a cached collection of "availables plugins" (available directory infos);
2. Reset that cache manually whenever a new folder is added under your standard folder for plugins (eg: under `wwwroot/Modules`).

Using a custom `FileProvider` based on `EmbeddedFileProvider` will also give you the ability to hide path elements. Eg: instead of browsing to "/Modules/Billing/Views/something.html" you'll be able to use "/Billing/Views/something.html".